# Angular 4 (AOT) + Electron and conditional import

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

New to Angular/Typescript and I'm working on a cross-platform Desktop application using Electron and Angular 4.
The problem I have is that I plan to use a Service in my different components but I want this service to be loaded from a different file depending on the platform the application is running

Just so you understand what I'm trying to achieve :

```
if (process.platform === 'darwin') { // Mac
   import { MyService } from './path/to/the/mac/service/file';
} else if (process.platform === 'windows' { // Windows
   import { MyService } from './path/to/the/windows/service/file';
}
```

And what bothers me is that I need to use AOT compilation, so I can't use require();

I hope someone already faced this kind of problem and could point me to the right direction.

Comment: A usual practice is to import both and switch between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems like a good place to use a [FactoryProvider](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider) as long as both services have the same interface. This pattern works with AOT in other applications I've worked on.

```
import { FactoryProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService as MySerivceWindows } from './path/to/the/windows/service/file';
import { MyService as MyServiceMac } from './path/to/the/mac/service/file';

export abstract class MyService{};

export function myFactoryProvider(){
       if (process.platform === 'darwin') { // Mac
            return new MyServiceMac();
       }else{
            return new MySeviceWindows();
       }
}

const MY_SERVICE_PROVIDER: FactoryProvider = {
     provide: MyService, 
     useFactory: myFactoryProvider
 };
```

You can then import and inject the abstract class into your components where needed.

it would also probably be best to provide the process and inject it as well in the deps for the factory.

Comment: Alright, after reading more about the subject, to achieve what I'm trying to do I need to import both of them no matter what approach I use to switch between the two. Thank you for your input ;)